# Why does Foursquare API Search for Venues not show cities like Copenhagen and Berlin, but does show New York and London?

Tags: api, foursquare

I am using the Foursquare API, and I need to let users search for cities and countries. Please see parameters below:

When calling the search, it shows some cities, but very many are excluded (Copenhagen, Berlin, Marrakech, Tokyo, Johannesburg to name a few)

```
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    v: 20182507,
    ll: this.state.location,
    intent: 'global',
    query: this.state.text,
    categoryId: states,
    limit: 5
```

I am getting zero venues as a response, but I would expect to get the correct cities, especially because it works on some, but not others.